# Problem when deploying my machine learing model in GCP SDK Shell

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) Uncompressed deployment is 1828184079B, bigger than maximum allowed size of 536870912B
```

And the function I am trying to deploy is this:

```
def predict(request):
    global model
    if model is None:
        download_blob(
            BUCKET_NAME,
            "models/adenocarcinoma_detection.h5",
            "/tmp/adenocarcinoma_detection.h5"
        )

        model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/tmp/adenocarcinoma_detection.h5")

    image = request.files["file"]

    image = np.array(Image.open(image).convert("RGB").resize(224, 224))
    img_array = tf.expand_dims(image / 255, 0)

    pred = model.predict(img_array)
    print(pred)

    predicted_class = CLASS_NAMES[np.argmax(pred[0])]
    confidence = round(100 * (np.max(pred[0])), 2)

    return {"Class": predicted_class, "Confidence": confidence}
```

I do not know why the model is that big, is a regular model for image classification done with tensorflow

The command used fot he deployment is the following:

```
gcloud functions deploy predict --runtime python38 --trigger-ht
tp --memory 512 --project adenocarcinoma-detection
```

I tried changing the "memory", making it bigger but it does not work

.gitignore file:`

```
.pycharm
__pycache__
.idea
.ipynb_checkpoints
models.config
```

.gcloudignore file:
`/venv/`

Comment: 1) Using Cloud Shell for Machine Learning is not a good choice. 2) You have a deploy size of 1.8 GB, but your question shows nothing about your deployment. Most likely you have included files and directories in the deployment that should be `ignored`. 3) Update your post with the deployment commands and their output.

Comment: @JohnHanley I just edit the post with the commnad and what I try to change it. How can I `ignore` files?

Comment: Your edit missed what we need. The file list that was included in the deployment. Something in your directory is filling up 1.8 GB of space.

Comment: @JohnHanley I figured out, it´s the `venv` folder, that where I have installed all my dependencies for the virtual enviroment. Is there any way to ignore that folder?

Comment: Yes, use `.gitignore` and/or `.gcloudignore`. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore

Comment: Post an answer once you configure the ignore file and confirm that it solves your problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley I just used it, but the code is not running, it just stays where the command was wrote without giving an output, is this normal? or just my low resources computer?

Comment: I don't know, no details for me to review. Edit your post and show the ignore file, which type you are using, and its current contents. Read the link I included in my comment first so that you know how to configure the ignore of folders and files.

Comment: I recommend just using one of .gitignore or .gcloudignore while you are learning. Use .gcloudignore for this problem. I don't yet understand what problem you are trying to tell me. Edit your post with details.

Comment: Note: you now know what your original problem was. Including files that should not be part of the deployment. For the new problem, start a section titled "PART 2" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I implement a `.gclooudignore` folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).